# How to create source and target ID columns for a linestring table in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have table paths_3D which has column "the_geom". I need to create a new column source_id which will have starting points from the geom. This statement doesn't work:

```
ALTER TABLE paths_3d ADD COLUMN source_id AS SELECT *, startpoint(the_geom)FROM paths_3d;
```

Comment: Please clarify: Do you already have a table of network nodes with IDs or do you need to create IDs from scratch? If you have a nodes table, how does it look like?

Comment: I had it, but I messed it up and I need to create everything again from scratch. So I imported my paths_3d.shp with shp2pgsql and executed file in phpPgAdmin tool. Now I have table paths_3d with gid, cat and the_geom column. Next step is to create source_id and target_id columns from the_geom column, is that right or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start and end node geometries

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW paths_3d_ext AS
  SELECT *, startpoint(the_geom), endpoint(the_geom)
  FROM paths_3d;
```

Creating node IDs

```
CREATE TABLE node AS
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY foo.p)::integer AS id,
         foo.p AS the_geom
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT paths_3d_ext.startpoint AS p FROM paths_3d_ext
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT paths_3d_ext.endpoint AS p FROM paths_3d_ext
  ) foo
  GROUP BY foo.p;
```

Finally, a routable network table

```
CREATE TABLE network AS
  SELECT a.*, b.id as start_id, c.id as end_id
  FROM paths_3d_ext AS a
    JOIN node AS b ON a.startpoint = b.the_geom
    JOIN node AS c ON a.endpoint = c.the_geom
```

... Like in my [pgRouting guide](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/).

Comment: I did it succesfully, thank you. Now I need to name some nodes, but I need to see them in some gui, because I don't know where are they just by id or something. How can I name it?

Comment: After adding a name column to nodes table, you can use QGIS to view and edit the nodes table.

Comment: I can't connect to database through QGIS and SPIT, it returns error. I'm using the same parameters like those in Mapfile for connecting to database. Is there any other solution except QGIS?

Comment: You don't need SPIT. Use "Add PostGIS layer". If it doesn't work: What error message are you getting? Is the database running on your local computer?

Comment: I tried with Add PostGIS layer but it gives me error: "could not connect to server: Connection timed out. Is the server running on host "www.something.com" and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5433?" Database is running on some other server, not on my local computer. When showing layer in Mapfile, I'm using the same parameters and it works great so I can't understand what's the difference.

Comment: By default Postgres is configured to ignore requests from other machines. It's only listening to localhost requests. You'll have to change Postgres' configuration. http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/postgres-allow-remote-access-tcp-connection.html

Comment: Ok, I don't have administrator rights so I would have to wait for it. Thank you for all your help :)